# How do I describe solutions to $Ax=0$ parametrically?

Tags: linear-algebra

$\begin{bmatrix}4&-1&2&-4\\
0&0&0&0\\
0&0&0&0\\
0&0&0&0\end{bmatrix}$

I understand that I have to do $x_1 = x_2 - 2x_3 + 4x_4$, but I don't know what to do from here.

The given answer in a matrix is:  $\begin{bmatrix}2&0&1\\0&2&0\\-2&1&0\\1&0&1\end{bmatrix}$

Comment: First off, it helps make your question clearer if you take the time to write things using [MathJax](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) and $\LaTeX$.  Secondly, you need to understand that what you are referring to is not writing the matrix parametrically... it is **writing the solution to the matrix equation $Ax=0$ parametrically**.  Third, with that matrix as $A$ and $x=[x_1,x_2,x_3,x_4]$ you have $Ax=0$ implies $\color{red}{4}x_1=x_2-2x_3+4x_4$.  You missed the coefficient of $x_1$.

Comment: As for how to continue, letting $x_2=r, x_3=s, x_4=t$ try to rewrite the vector $\begin{bmatrix}x_1\\x_2\\x_3\\x_4\end{bmatrix}$ in terms of a vector using $r,s,t$.  Then see if you can break it apart as a sum and factor out the variables.

Comment: I don't understand where the 4 goes... do the  original matrix and the answer correlate? @jmoravitz

Comment: "*Do the original matrix and the answer correlate?*"  Yes.  If the original matrix is labelled $A$ and the given answer as a matrix is labelled $B$ you have $AB=0_{4\times 3}$

Answer (score 1):

$\begin{bmatrix}4&-1&2&-4\\0&0&0&0\\0&0&0&0\\0&0&0&0\end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix}x_1\\x_2\\x_3\\x_4\end{bmatrix}=\begin{bmatrix}0\\0\\0\\0\end{bmatrix}$

if and only if

$\begin{cases}4x_1-x_2+2x_3-4x_4=0\end{cases}$

if and only if

$\begin{cases}x_1=\frac{1}{4}x_2-\frac{1}{2}x_3+x_4\\ x_2=x_2\\ x_3=x_3\\ x_4=x_4\end{cases}$

Letting $x_2=r, x_3=s, x_4=t$ this system implies

$\begin{cases} x_1=\frac{1}{4}r-\frac{1}{2}s+t\\x_2=r\\x_3=s\\x_4=t\end{cases}$

if and only if

$\begin{bmatrix}x_1\\x_2\\x_3\\x_4\end{bmatrix}=\begin{bmatrix}\frac{1}{4}r-\frac{1}{2}s+t\\r\\s\\t\end{bmatrix} = \begin{bmatrix}\frac{1}{4}r\\r\\0\\0\end{bmatrix}+\begin{bmatrix}-\frac{1}{2}s\\0\\s\\0\end{bmatrix}+\begin{bmatrix}t\\0\\0\\t\end{bmatrix} = r\begin{bmatrix}\frac{1}{4}\\1\\0\\0\end{bmatrix}+s\begin{bmatrix}-\frac{1}{2}\\0\\1\\0\end{bmatrix}+t\begin{bmatrix}1\\0\\0\\1\end{bmatrix}$

We see then that the solution set to the matrix equation $Ax=0$ is:

$\{x~:~Ax=0\} = \left\{r\begin{bmatrix}\frac{1}{4}\\1\\0\\0\end{bmatrix}+s\begin{bmatrix}-\frac{1}{2}\\0\\1\\0\end{bmatrix}+t\begin{bmatrix}1\\0\\0\\1\end{bmatrix}~:~r,s,t\in\Bbb R\right\}$

---

As an aside, the given answer is **also** gives a correct basis for the solution set but it is just written differently.  The span of the vectors in your given answer is in fact the same as the span of the vectors I write above.  This can be seen by the fact that each of the vectors in the given answer are in fact solutions to $Ax=0$ and further that they are linearly independent.  We can also see that the dimension of the solution set must be three by the rank-nullity theorem.  Thus they span the entirety of the solution set just the same as the vectors I give do.

In fact, there are *infinitely many* correct parametrizations of the solution space.

The general method I employ above (row reducing the matrix, assigning parameters to the free variables, and breaking apart based on those parameters) I find to be relatively routine and well defined and avoids the difficulty of being able to spot solutions "*by inspection*" which is likely the method used to get the given answers.